# Save knockout viewmodel temporarily and retrieve

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to store the viewmodel in knockout js to an array and on button click i am trying to reload the saved viewmodel. But all the observables in the viewmodel are not getting populated correctly.

The binding is as below

```
Category:
<select id="ddlctgry" data-bind="options:categories,optionsCaption:'select',value:selCatgy"></select>
</br>Model:
<select id="ddlmodel" data-bind="options:Products, optionsText:'modelName',optionsCaption:'-select-',value:selectedModel"></select>
</br>
<button id="add" type="button">Add New</button>
<button id="retold" type="button">Retrieve Old</button>
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9myr6/2/

First I select the category and model from the corresponding dropdown lists(like **Category:'A3 MFP-A3 MFP'**,**Model:'Phasor 6500'**) and on click of "Add New" button I am saving the app view model to an array and loading new viewmodel.

After making the selections in new view model(like **Category:'Printers-Mono'**,**Model:'3600'**), if i click on "Retrieve Old" button the "Category" dropdown is getting binded correctly.

But the model dropdown is not taking the previous stored value.

Can anyone help me on how this can be achieved, how can i bind model also from old viewmodel data.

Comment: You can use knockout mapping plugin to temporary save the data. You can dump the viewmodel object in a temporary object (with ko.mapping.toJS) or string (with ko.mapping.toJSON) and at the right time you can reload those values (ko.mapping.fromJS / ko.mapping.fromJSON).

Comment: I tried by using mapping plugin also but after "Retrieve Old" button click the model dropdown is not getting bind with old selection